# Need to delete multiply records from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called **TEST**

```
------------------------------------------  
ID  name          intime            
------------------------------------------      
1   ABC           2015-09-03 10:00:00       
1   ABC           2015-09-03 10:00:00       
2   XYZ           2015-09-03 11:00:00       
2   XYZ           2015-09-03 11:00:00
```

My objective is to delete the duplicate records from a table like for ABC intime is duplicate. And i have multiple records not just 4 its just for an example.

I am trying something like this

```
with cte as 
(
select id,InTime ,count(*) as c
from intime as m
where InTime between convert(varchar(10),'2015-09-01 00:01:00',103) and convert(varchar(10),'2015-09-30 00:01:00',103)
group by id,InTime
having count(*) > 1
)
select * from cte
order by ID
```

**Output**

```
id  InTime                 c    
----------------------------------  
1   2015-09-03 10:00:00    2    
2   2015-09-03 11:00:00    2
```

This query will give me the records which is having multiple intime on same date

```
with cte as 
(
select ID, inTime,
row_number() over (partition by convert(varchar(10),intime,103) order by intime desc) as r
from intime
where ID in (1)
and
inTime between '2015-09-01 00:01:00' and '2015-09-30 23:59:59'
)
select * from cte

delete  from cte
where r > 1
```

And this is the query which will remove the duplicate entry.

Problem which i am facing is I have to enter ID manually 1 by 1, If i do something where ID in (1,2)

It gives me output as :

```
ID  inTime              r   
2   2015-09-03 11:00:00 1   
2   2015-09-03 11:00:00 2   
1   2015-09-03 10:00:00 3   
1   2015-09-03 10:00:00 4
```

And then if i delete r>1 it will delete 3 rows.

I want to create something where I can delete all the duplicate records from the table. I am using sql-2008. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: I am using row_number in my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
with abc as
  (
  select * ,rn=ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by ID ,name,intime order by columnName)from yourtablename
  )

  delete from abc where rn>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not copying data into a new table with a DISTINCT ?

-- copy ...
select DISTINCT * into tmp_yourtablename from yourtablename

-- drop the original datas
truncate table yourtablename

-- reload them...
insert yourtablename  select * from tmp_yourtablename

-- drop the tmp_yourtablename  when all is finish...